# Efficient way to set 100% height for all the parents

Tags: css

I want a div to be 100% height of the viewport. The basic code is this:

http://jsfiddle.net/c247opd6/

Now, in a real web page the situation would be more like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/akrv5cgm/ my div nested inside some other divs.

I know the code of the second example doesn't work because in order for an element to have 100% of the height of its parent, its parent must either have an explicitly defined height or be 100% of the height of its parent. The fix:

```
.four, .three, .two {
      height: 100%;
}
```

However as soon as you start adding code this solution becomes harder and harder to mantain. Is there a shorter css rule which would allow me to set a 100% height to all the parent divs? Like nth-child, except for parents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want a div to be 100% height of the viewport.

You could use viewport relative units:

> [**5.1.2. Viewport-percentage lengths: the ‘vw’, ‘vh’, ‘vmin’, ‘vmax’ units**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)
>
> The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the initial containing block. When the height or width of the initial containing block is changed, they are scaled accordingly.

In this case you would use `height: 100vh`, where `1vh` is equivalent to `1%` of the viewport.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/jLzdruj2/)

```
.one {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: red
}
```

Browser support for these units can be [found here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

It's worth pointing out that the element won't take the height of its direct parent into consideration.

Comment: Thanks. The IE support is kinda meh (who would have thought? /sarcasm)